# Can angular $timeout be used as a reliable dom ready?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working with a library which need to be called after dom ready. And I just used the init function with $timeout from the controller's init.

Can $timeout be used as a reliable dom ready event ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need `$timeout`. Angular bootstrap itself starts after DOM is ready. Use the `module.run` function to do some intialization if required once. Else what you are doing will work without using `$timeout`.

Comment: you can check if it's ready in your function than needs it so, and timeout(arguments.callee) if not ready yet.

Comment: No need, just use a directive. The element has to exist for directive link function to fire

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AngularJS will bootstrap the application when the static DOM content is loaded. You can see from the diagram below, that AngularJS also has a dynamic DOM which is built when the directives are compiled and linked.

[image]

You can rely on $timeout called from inside of your directive's link function to execute after the $digest cycle has executed and all the models on scope have stabalised:

```
link: function() {
    $timeout(function() {
       // after $digest
       // dynamic DOM ready
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice. Kind of see the problem why I had to resort to timeout. The plugin depends on the dynamic dom created by Angular. Is there way to initialize the plugin after teh dynmaic dom is done ?